# Accord du participe passé avec mise en relief, interrogation, et négation

Tags: accord, participe-passé, inversion

Considérons le problème classique de l'accord du participe passé employé avec avoir :

> Il a perdu sa montre.
>
> La montre qu'il a perdu**e**.

Dans le cas d'une mise en relief du COD avec "c'est ... que", il est clair que l'accord se fait aussi (variante d'un exemple de Grevisse, 14e édition, 456 a) :

> C'est sa montre qu'il a perdu**e**.

Ma question est : que se passe-t-il pour une phrase interrogative ? Soit lorsqu'il n'y a pas d'inversion (langue parlée) :

> C'est sa montre qu'il a [perdu/perdu**e**] ?

ou avec inversion :

> Est-ce sa montre qu'il a [perdu/perdu**e**] ?

L'accord semble déjà plus douteux : est-ce que "sa montre" est vraiment COD dans ce cas ?

Même question s'il y a une négation (avec interrogation, avec ou sans inversion) :

> N'est-ce pas sa montre qu'il a [perdu/perdu**e**] ?
>
> Ce n'est pas sa montre qu'il a [perdu/perdu**e**] ?
>
> Ce n'est pas sa montre qu'il a [perdu/perdu**e**].

Par exemple l'accord suivant me paraîtrait franchement douteux :

> Ce n'est pas une pipe qu'il a dessiné**e**.

(Sauf si le sens est, mettons : "Ce n'est pas une pipe qu'il a dessinée, mais une pipe qu'il a peinte.")

J'ai parcouru les sections du Grevisse sur l'accord du participe passé avec avoir, la mise en relief, et les donneurs d'accord complexes, et je n'ai rien vu de concluant (mais je ne suis même pas sûr de comment les phrases en question s'analysent).

Comment: Dans tous ces cas, le COD est le "qu", correspondant à la montre. L'accord se fait donc toujours.

Comment: @Damien: En êtes-vous vraiment sûr ? j'ai ajouté d'autres exemples à la fin

Comment: Les pronoms relatifs prennent le genre du mot qu'ils remplacent. Vous diriez par exemple "j'ai vu cette fille, qui est blonde". C'est valable pour les COD comme pour les sujets. Concernant les phrases négatives, je ne vois pas d'autres possibilités que l'accord. Sinon, quel genre affecter au pronom relatif ? Le genre neutre n'existe pas en français.

Comment: Oui, mais il n'y a pas toujours d'accord, même quand il y a un COD. Par exemple : "Des pipes, il en a dessiné !". Je ne suis pas certain non plus que le "que" dans mes exemples s'analyse comme un pronom relatif.

Comment: Vous faites allusion à Duchamp je suppose. Effectivement ici il n'y as pas accord mais il me semble que c'est un cas différent. Il y a pas de pronom relatif. On écrit par exemple "Ce livre est une mine d'or, je ne te dis pas les enseignements que j'en ai tirés", le COD étant le "que".

Comment: Dans la phrase "Des pipes, il en a dessiné !", le COD est "en", qui n'a ni genre ni nombre.

Comment: @Damien Existerait-il des points de vue variés en ce qui concerne le genre et le nombre des pronoms « en » et « y » ? On trouve par exemple au site [CCDMD](https://www.ccdmd.qc.ca/media/pron_14Accords.pdf) que ces pronoms sont considérés comme ayant le genre et nombre de leur antécédant. S'agit-il d'un nouveau point de vue ?

Comment: @LPH Je suis un peu surpris par ce qu'écrit ce site CCDMD. Ça ne correspond pas à ce que je croyais. Je sais que l'accord avec "en" pose problème. Ce site par exemple donne quelque éléments: http://www.aidenet.eu/conjugaison44.htm . Mais je ne suis pas un spécialiste, et ça nous éloigne un peu de la question initiale du post.

Comment: @LPH Sur ce site réputé, un expert mentionne qu'il y a désaccord sur ces règles : https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/des-erreurs-j-en-ai-fait-ou-des-erreurs-j-en-ai-faites/

Comment: @Damien Je vois, il existe bien une divergence reconnue de points de vue, mais on aurait tendance à préférer considérer ces pronoms comme neutres. Une telle information serait vraiment utile dans les entrées de dictionnaire …

Answer (score 3):

Le mot « que » dans tous les exemples donnés est un pronom relatif COD, et il est placé avant le verbe ; donc le participe passé s'accorde avec ce COD.

Answer (score 0):

J'ai fini par me convaincre que l'accord devait se faire dans tous les exemples que je donnais, en me rendant compte que la difficulté n'était pas spécifique à l'accord du participe passé avec avoir. En effet, on peut reprendre mes exemples avec un adjectif attribut (on pourrait aussi le faire avec un participe passé employé avec "être") :

> La montre est perdu**e**.
>
> C'est sa montre qui est perdu**e**.
>
> C'est sa montre qui est perdu**e** ?
>
> Est-ce sa montre qui est perdu**e** ?
>
> N'est-ce pas sa montre qui est perdu**e** ?
>
> Ce n'est pas sa montre qui est perdu**e** ?
>
> Ce n'est pas sa montre qui est perdu**e**.
>
> Ce n'est pas une pipe qui est dessiné**e**.

On se convainc sans peine que l'accord est inévitable ; c'est encore plus frappant avec un participe passé où la différence s'entend à l'oreille, comme :

> Ce n'est pas une pipe qui est mis**e** sur la table.

Ainsi, la mise en relief, l'interrogation, la négation, sont sans effet sur l'accord, et il faut bien écrire :

> Ce n'est pas une pipe qu'il a dessiné**e**.

et de même pour mes autres exemples.